# C# SQL Server Update, If not exists, insert new records

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using the following code in the button click event to update the values. If the row does not exist yet, I want to insert a new row into the table. But the code does not execute when I click on the button. Both the stored procedures are just regular insert and update SQL statements.

Any thoughts? Thank you so much!

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.GetConnectionString());                       

SqlCommand cmdnew = new SqlCommand();
cmdnew.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdnew.Connection = con;
cmdnew.CommandText = "dbo.UpdateMagtoSpec";

cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecNo", DropDownList1.SelectedText);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestID", ddl_testclass.SelectedValue);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Max", TextBox6.Text);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Typical", TextBox8.Text);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Min", TextBox7.Text);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextArea2.Text);
cmdnew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", ddl_units.SelectedText);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = null;
rdr = cmdnew.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    try
    {
        cmdnew.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Alert.Show("Changes Saved!", MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        btn_edit.Hidden = false;
        Button1.Hidden = true;
        Button2.Hidden = true;

        TextBox6.Readonly = true;
        TextBox7.Readonly = true;
        TextBox8.Readonly = true;
        ddl_units.Readonly = true;
        TextArea2.Readonly = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.ToString().Contains("Error"))
        {
            Alert.Show("Modification Failed!", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }                

    con.Close();                
}
else
{                
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.InsertMagtoSpec";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecNo", DropDownList1.SelectedText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestID", ddl_testclass.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Max", TextBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Typical", TextBox8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Min", TextBox7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextArea2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", ddl_units.SelectedText);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Alert.Show("Records Saved!", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.ToString().Contains("Error"))
        {
            Alert.Show("Modification Failed!", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Why don't you merge the two procs, something like `UpsertMagtoSpec` and in there check if the record exists, then update, else insert.

Comment: @Sam nothing happens when I click on the button. There is no errors . Thanks.

Comment: @Habib yes, i could do that, but how could I call from the button click event. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to use @Habib, suggestion, then what you can do, is before you do an `insert` do a `sql` query to check if that row exists. If it does, then use `update`, else use `insert`. However, I do suggest that you `debug` your code. Put a stop on `button click event` and step through it. You will see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your aspx code with the button click declaration. Most probably you have to wire the code to the event.

You need both parts:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
           Text="Click here for greeting..."
           OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
```

And

```
void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender,
                           EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the button is clicked,
}
```